# Implementing a faster inbound neighbour similarity in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, pandas

Given a directed graph **G** of 20+ million edges and approximately 2 million unique nodes, can this function/process be made faster on a dataset of 40k edges?

The current speed is at ~1.8 seconds per edge.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# main feature calculator
def jacard_inbound(u,v):
    preds = G.predecessors(v)
    result = [jacard_coef(u,x) for x in preds]
    return sum(result), max(result), sum(result)/len(result)


# jacquard's coefficient & helper functions
def jacard_coef(u,v):
    return common_friends(u,v)/total_friends(u,v)

def total_friends(u,v):
    return len(set(Gamma(u)).union(Gamma(v)))

def common_friends(u,v):
    return len(set(Gamma(u)).intersection(Gamma(v)))

# to cache calculated results
gamma_dict = dict()   
def Gamma(u):
    s = gamma_dict.get(u)
    if s is None:
        s = set(G.successors(u)).union(G.predecessors(u))
        gamma_dict[u]=s
    return s
```

Running example:

```
# sample graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5), (7,1), (5,6), (8,2), (9,0)])

# sample edges
dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['source','target'])
dataset['target'] = [3, 6, 2, 3]
dataset['source'] = [2, 1, 8, 1] 

t = time.time()
dataset['jacard_inbound'] = dataset[['source','target']].apply(lambda x: jacard_inbound(x['source'],x['target']), axis=1)
print(time.time() - t)
```

Comment: Can you explain what the program is supposed to do?

Comment: @GarethRees to compute the inbound Jacard Coefficient sum, maximum and average for each edge. It basically computes a ratio of the amount of common neighbors between the source node and the nodes that follow the target.

Comment: The example does not work for me since it does not define the graph `G`.

Comment: @GarethRees I updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Jaccard coefficient", not "Jacard" or "Jacquard": it's named after [Paul Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Jaccard).
2. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do? What do they return?
3. The results of these functions depend on the global variable `G`. If you ever needed to generalize your program to operate on more than one graph at a time this dependency would become very inconvenient. The functions ought to either take the graph as an argument, or be methods on the graph class.
4. Is `Gamma` standard graph terminology for this function? I've seen it called '[neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory))' (or 'open neighbourhood' when it needs to be clear that `u` is not included).
5. Python has a built-in decorator [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for caching the results of a function. So you can write:

   ```
   @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
   def neighbourhood(g, u):
       "Return the set of vertices in the graph g that are adjacent to u."
       return set(g.successors(u)).union(g.predecessors(u))
   ```
6. Reuse the set of successors instead of discarding it:

   ```
   @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
   def neighbourhood(g, u):
       "Return the set of vertices in the graph g that are adjacent to u."
       result = set(g.successors(u))
       result.update(g.predecessors(u))
       return result
   ```
7. In `common_friends` and `total_friends`, there is no need to make a copy of the neighbourhood before taking the union/intersection. You can take the union/intersection directly:

   ```
   def total_friends(g, u, v):
       """Return the number of vertices in the graph g that are in the
       neighbourhoods of u or v (or both).

       """
       return len(neighbourhood(g, u) | neighbourhood(g, v))

   def common_friends(g, u, v):
       """Return the number of vertices in the graph g that are in the
       neighbourhoods of both u and v.

       """
       return len(neighbourhood(g, u) & neighbourhood(g, v))
   ```